# Play video file in Sencha touch 2

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

```
 Ext.define('Video.view.video', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',

        requires: [
            'Ext.Video'
        ],
        config: {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'video',
                url: ['aa.mp4'],
                loop: true,
                posterUrl: 'resources/images/cover.jpg'
            }]
        }
    });
```

> this is my code, but not display video

Answer (score 0):

Please @Amit kumar can you try something like this,

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Video', {
   extend: 'Ext.Container',
   xtype: 'myvideo',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Video'
    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'video',
                enableControls: false,
                x : 600,
                y : 300,
                width : 300,
                height   : 250,
                url: 'app/images/VID.3GP',
                loop: true,
                posterUrl: 'app/images/transfers.png'
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

**I hope this helps. :)**

[image]

Comment: Dear hekomobile, i have already use this code but does not play video

Comment: Please enable the controls to `true`. :)

Comment: Amit, i am also stuck in the problem. Have you got any solution??